# How could I simplify this multiple dependent calls with RxJava2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'd like to know how to perform something like the following with RxJava2,

- make an API call to get a list of items
- iterate over the list of items

  - if the item is of specific type

    - make an API call to get user details
    - make an API call to get a list of data with the item id & user name (from details)
    - iterate over the list of data

      - if the data item code matches the item code (from outer loop)

        - update the item in the outer list by copying data item to it
- return the list

Am pretty new to RxJava and tried doing this with a `Single` for the initial API call and then using the `map` operator, and in the Mapper function then just did the rest of the stuff with a normal outer and inner loop.

I'd really love to know if the mapper function part could also somehow be done with RxJava in a simpler way rather than using the nested loops?

Comment: Please provide your model classes

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop might look like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable( list )
  .flatMap( item -> checkItemAndReplace( item ) )
  .toList();
```

and the inner loop could be:

```
Observable<ItemType> checkItemAndReplace( ItemType item ) {
  if ( isItemOfSpecificType( item ) ) {
    return getUpdatesForItem( item );
  }
  return Observable.just( item );
}
```

and so on for the inner loop. I broke things down into nested function calls returning observables, but you can recombine them into an observable chain, depending on your code style and testing needs.

The points to note:

1. You can convert to and from normal data structures with various observable operators. `fromIterable()` and `just()` convert to observables, while `toList()` converts back to a list.
2. Use `map()` when the operation converts from one value to another or one non-observable to another; use `flatMap()` when you need to convert an observable to the values it produces.

Comment: thanks will give that a try and post back. btw do you know if it would be the same when using a `Single` as well?

Comment: The issue with using `Single` instead of `Observable` for `checkItemAndReplace()` is that you will have to convert it to `Observable` for the `flatMap()` operator. If `getUpdatesForItem()` returns a `Single`, then you would want to convert it to `Observable` in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the *Api* interface and the *itemsToBeRefreshed* Observable. You may may use *Observable.fromIterable* in order to iterate over a list and *flatMap* to chain different api calls. Also if you have a request-response behaviour, you should use Single as return type. Furthermore do not change properties of items in the stream. Just copy over the items to be changed into a new object and write them back.

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Api api = mock(Api.class);

    when(api.getItems()).thenReturn(Single.just(Arrays.asList(
            new Item(0, 123),
            new Item(1, 123),
            new Item(2, 333)
    )));

    when(api.getUserDetails(eq(0))).thenReturn(Single.just(new UserDetails("hans wurst", 0)));
    when(api.getUserDetails(eq(1))).thenReturn(Single.just(new UserDetails("mett wurst", 1)));
    when(api.getUserDetails(eq(2))).thenReturn(Single.just(new UserDetails("kaese wurst", 2)));

    when(api.getData(eq(0), eq("hans wurst"))).thenReturn(Single.just(new Data(123)));
    when(api.getData(eq(1), eq("mett wurst"))).thenReturn(Single.just(new Data(123)));
    when(api.getData(eq(2), eq("kaese wurst"))).thenReturn(Single.just(new Data(666)));

    Observable<Item> itemsToBeRefreshed = api.getItems()
            .flatMapObservable(strings -> Observable.fromIterable(strings))
            .filter(s -> s instanceof Item) // test for specific type
            .flatMapMaybe(item -> api.getUserDetails(item.id)
                    .flatMap(userDetails -> api.getData(userDetails.id, userDetails.userName))
                    .filter(data -> data.code == item.code)
                    .map(data -> new Item(-1, -1)) // create new Item and copy properties over from data
            );

    itemsToBeRefreshed.test()
            .assertValueCount(2);

    // subscribe to 'itemsToBeRefreshed' in order to write back items or just chain it to itemsToBeRefreshed with doOnNext
}

interface Api {
    Single<List<Item>> getItems();

    Single<UserDetails> getUserDetails(int id);

    Single<Data> getData(int id, String userName);
}

class Item {
    int id;

    int code;

    Item(int id, int code) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
    }
}

class UserDetails {
    String userName;
    int id;

    UserDetails(String userName, int id) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Data {
    int code;

    Data(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```